# Trick to identify object property of popup window for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, dom, popup

In my application when I click some link it opens a popup window. In this window I need to perform some action like click. But I am unable to identify any property of those objects.

My application only works with **ie** . F12 for the new pop window not working. I can't perform any right click on the window by which i might able to do "inspect element".

#### Looking for some trick or guidance or coding(in java) through which I may get the properties.

Need your help badly as I am stuck. Thanks a ton in advance for your help.

*Below information may help you to understand what I have tried -->*

As UFT is able to identify all the properties I took them ,I am able to perform action on those object.  **But I can't use UFT every time.** I followed below steps after getting the properties by UFT -->

1. Switched to new window.
2. Switchd to frame
3. Click on the Object with property as "name" and value as "sign"

I have attached UFT-Object selection hierarchy and the popup window here.

[UFT-Object selection hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvDf.png)

[popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjeg2.png)

Answer (score 0):

See if the below approach works

```
a)Use below code to get pagesource of popup/new window

String parentHandle=driver.getWindowhandle(); //returns current window handle
//Perform click action that opens the new pop up
List<String> allHandles=driver.getWindowhandles();//return all window handles opened by current driver instance
  while(allHandles.hasNext()){
    if (allHandles!=parentHandle){
        WebDriver popup=driver.switchTo.window(allHandles);
     }
  }
String popupPageSource=popup.getPageSource(); //provides page source of popup

b)Snippet below should work since you already know the frame name

driver.switchTo().frame("FRAME_NAME");
String framePageSource=driver.getPageSource();//provides page source of frame
```